# ExecutionHandler In Netty 4.0.8

Tags: netty

Is there a handler like ExecutionHandler in Netty 4.x?

My server is having a very big latency, and I think ExecutionHandler would help me fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify a EventExecutor when adding the ChannelHandler to the ChannelPipeline.